# How I choose the value that appears by default in a SelectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu

I would like that in the `selectItem`, instead of giving me a value, it would default to one of those in `selectItems` where I have 6 values.

Let's say I want the 4 to appear, could it be done?

my code:

```
<div class="row group">
<h:outputLabel for="critEjec" value="#{msg['cod_ejec']}" styleClass="nombreCampo" />
<h:selectOneMenu id="critEjec" value="#{maestroSubCategoriasBean.critEjec}" styleClass="campo">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['comunes_seleccionarTodos']}" itemValue="-1" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{maestroSubCategoriasController.comboListaEjesCatalogacion}" />
    <a4j:support event="onchange" action="#{maestroSubCategoriasController.llenarComboCategorias}" reRender="CategoriasPanel,mensajesPanel" ajaxSingle="true" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: if you ignore your problem for now, where does the value you actively select in the ui end up? Tried assigning a value upfront to that same field?

Comment: The `#{maestroSubCategoriasBean.critEjec}` represents the selected value.

Comment: Sorry, im new, now i got this: <f:selectItem value="#{maestroSubCategoriasController.comboListaEjesCatalogacion.get(4)}" />
             <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['comunes_seleccionarTodos']}" itemValue="-1" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{maestroSubCategoriasController.comboListaEjesCatalogacion}"/> but i got duplicated one item

Comment: The `<f:selectItem(s)>` does not represent the selected value. They represent the available values. Instead, the `#{maestroSubCategoriasBean.critEjec}` represents the selected value, as explained in my previous comment. In case you missed it, there's a duplicate link in top of your question.